# Multiple database users On a Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-postgresql

i want to know how do i set an http log in form to send that user and password to the database.yml file, so with that user and password, log into the database.

This because i have multiple database users with different privileges.

thanks for any help you reply to me.

Database is Postgresql (if it matters, dont think so but i bet maybe someone will ask)

Comment: Rails isn't really built that way. Database.yml provides databse access to the entire application. Usually you would handle authentication and authorization to specific application functions and data through your code.

Comment: Wait, you want to allow access to your application based on database credentials?

Comment: Well, i see now that what i want to do cant happen... one way i can have several databse users on the app, its to run the app from each computer... since its a class project using two physical machines and four virtual machines, i can install rails on each one and run the app. Of course i will have to configure each of the database.yml to connect to the one machine running the database. What do you think of this?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is looking for an answer to this question.

Although it is only an overview see tip 21 from this [presentation from James Edward Gray](http://speakerdeck.com/u/jeg2/p/10-things-you-didnt-know-rails-could-do). It walks through, at a high level, an approach to creating and using a different database for each user. It's a long presentation, this tip is about a third of the way through.

It may be enough to point you in the right direction.